# Mysql creating view two different count of same data in different condition with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I want create a view to show count data from these 3 tables some "with where condition", some "without where condition".

The place where I am counting COUNT(e.user_id) two times 1st time without any WHERE clause 2nd time its counting with "WHERE e.reg_date = CURDATE()"

For the 1st section its not working, when I want to get total number of user_id without any where clause, it by default its taking "WHERE e.reg_date= CURDATE()" for both cases.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW admin_summary AS (
SELECT COUNT(e.user_id) AS total_register_user, COUNT(e.user_id) AS register_today, COUNT(d.pr_status) AS total_pending_payment , COUNT(f.status) AS total_pending_account, COUNT(g.time) AS failed_login_today
FROM client e, payment d, masterbroker f, login_attempts g
WHERE e.reg_date = CURDATE() AND d.pr_status = 'pending' AND f.status ='pending' AND g.time = CURDATE()
  );
```

**UPDATE 1:** data records:
total number of registered user 2 (for all time)
register today: 0
total pending payment: 1
total pending account: 1
failed log in : 1

This is how it shows up with scaisEdge code.
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
data sample
client table
[image]

masterbroker
[image]

payment 
[image]

**UPDATE 3:**

Due to the datatype confusion, I changed the login attempt time into datetime.

login attempt 
[image]

**Update 4:** With Debug Result
It seems without where condition it works at some point. But I need it with Where condition.
Here is the result of without where clause:

```
     SELECT COUNT(e.user_id) AS total_register_user , SUM( CASE WHEN 
    date(e.reg_date) = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS register_today , 
    COUNT(d.pr_status) AS total_pending_payment , 
    COUNT(f.status) AS total_pending_account , 
    COUNT(g.time) AS failed_login_today 
   from client e INNER JOIN payment d on e.user_id = d.user_id 
   INNER JOIN masterbroker f on e.user_id = f.user_id 
   INNER JOIN login_attempts g on e.user_id = g.user_id
```

[image]
But total registered user it showing 1 actually it should be 2.

**Update 5:** more information about unique indexes if it required.
 User_id is the PK for client table & forgien key for other 3 table, payment, login_attempts & masterbroker. I have following unique indexes:

```
masterbrokerindex ON masterbroker(user_id,accountno, broker_id);
paymentindex ON payment(user_id,pr_rqtime);
login_attempts_index ON login_attempts (user_id,ip);
```

Comment: I don't understand the wording of your question, but `COUNT(e.user_id)` will give the same result every time you use it.

Comment: Hello, I edited the wording. But I need different result 1st with total number of user_id 2nd only for user registered today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking only to the relevent part of the question  for get two different count of same datas 
 in different condition  you should use a self join  use the tabl in two different way

```
 SELECT 
    COUNT(e1.user_id) AS total_register_user
  , COUNT(e2.user_id) AS register_today
from client e1 
left join client e2 on e1.user_id = e2.user_id and e2.reg_date = CURDATE();
....
```

or avoinding join you can use a CASE WHEN for filter the e.reg_date

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(e.user_id) AS total_register_user
  , SUM( CASE WHEN   e.reg_date = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS register_today
  from client e 
  .....
```

In your query there is not condition for relation between tables . this is pretty unusual  ..

and  based on your date columns data type (assuming that e.reg_date is a datetime  and g.time is a unix time stamp)

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW admin_summary AS (
  SELECT 
      COUNT(e.user_id) AS total_register_user
    , SUM( CASE WHEN   date(e.reg_date) = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS register_today
    , COUNT(d.pr_status) AS total_pending_payment 
    , COUNT(f.status) AS total_pending_account
    , COUNT(g.time) AS failed_login_today
    from client e, payment d, masterbroker f, login_attempts g
  WHERE date(e.reg_date) = CURDATE() 
  AND d.pr_status = 'pending' 
  AND f.status ='pending' 
  AND date(g.time) = CURDATE()
  );
```

for the join between the tables  try using

the use of where in left join work as an inner join so the where condition should be corrispondant on clause in the related  on clays

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW admin_summary AS (
SELECT 
    COUNT(e.user_id) AS total_register_user
  , SUM( CASE WHEN   date(e.reg_date) = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS register_today
  , COUNT(d.pr_status) AS total_pending_payment 
  , COUNT(f.status) AS total_pending_account
  , COUNT(g.time) AS failed_login_today
  from client e
  LEFT JOIN payment d on e.user_id = d.user_id 
            AND  date(e.reg_date) = CURDATE() 
            AND d.pr_status = 'pending' 
  LEFT JOIN masterbroker f on e.user_id = f.user_id
            AND f.status ='pending' 
  LEFT JOIN login_attempts g on e.user_id = g.user_id
            AND date(g.time) = CURDATE()
);
```

and if you don't need  a join on client for payment  you could try

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW admin_summary AS (
  SELECT 
      COUNT(e.user_id) AS total_register_user
    , SUM( CASE WHEN   date(e.reg_date) = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS register_today
    , COUNT(d.pr_status) AS total_pending_payment 
    , COUNT(f.status) AS total_pending_account
    , COUNT(g.time) AS failed_login_today
    from client e
    LEFT JOIN  payment d ON  d.pr_status = 'pending' 
    LEFT JOIN masterbroker f on e.user_id = f.user_id
              AND f.status ='pending' 
    LEFT JOIN login_attempts g on e.user_id = g.user_id

    WHERE date(e.reg_date) = CURDATE()          
  );
```

and at last  .. try calculating pending_payment without any join

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW admin_summary AS (
  SELECT 
      COUNT(e.user_id) AS total_register_user
    , SUM( CASE WHEN   date(e.reg_date) = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS register_today
    , (select COUNT(pr_status) from payment where pr_status = 'pending' ) AS total_pending_payment 
    , COUNT(f.status) AS total_pending_account
    , COUNT(g.time) AS failed_login_today
    from client e
     LEFT JOIN masterbroker f on e.user_id = f.user_id
              AND f.status ='pending' 
    LEFT JOIN login_attempts g on e.user_id = g.user_id
              AND date(g.time) = CURDATE()
  );
```